# Vue auto update the total value if the id's are same in cart

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

In below code (i try to include like [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) but my code is not working there) I have home and cart page, the cart page(component) is imported in Home page. My problem is whenever I added a new item to my card (for the first time is is perfect) and when the same `ID` is already in cart, then it updates the data (like add-ons, total price, etc) exactly like the latest data. When I create the `route` for cart and goes to that route after creating another item and data is not updated. I'm new to vue and cannot debug why that's happen.

What I want is whenever we create new item and added to cart I want that particular data(item) doesn't affect the previous item (when `ID's` are matching).

If it is not same ID, then no problem. And I don't have cart table, because guest(only) have to order the item by providing details, no need to store their data in DB.

Belows are my code, thanks in advance

My Home.vue

```
   <template>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col sm="12" md="9">
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" md="4" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
              <v-card class="mx-auto">
                <v-img class="white--text align-end" height="350px" :src="item.image">
                  <v-card-title
                    style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); padding: 6px; padding-left: 20px"
                  >{{ item.item_name.substring(0,32)+"..." }}</v-card-title>
                </v-img>

                <v-card-actions>
                  ₹ {{ item.price }}
                  <v-spacer />
                  <v-btn color="orange" icon outlined @click="addToCart(item)">
                    <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3" class="d-none d-md-flex">
          <v-card>
            <Cart />
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <!-- add to cart dialog -->
      <v-dialog v-model="addDialog" width="1000">
        <v-card>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" md="4">
                <v-img :src="selected.image" class="mb-3"></v-img>
                <v-label>
                  {{ selected.item_name }}
                  <br />
                  Price : ₹{{selected.price}}
                </v-label>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" md="8">
                <v-label>Select Adds On</v-label>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <label class="typo__label">Xtra</label>
                    <multiselect
                      v-model="addOnExtra"
                      placeholder="Select extra"
                      :custom-label="nameWithPrice"
                      track-by="id"
                      :options="addOns.Xtra"
                      :multiple="true"
                      :taggable="true"
                      @tag="addTag"
                      @input="addExtra()"
                    ></multiselect>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <label class="typo__label">Crust</label>
                    <multiselect
                      v-model="addOnCrust"
                      track-by="id"
                      :custom-label="nameWithPrice"
                      placeholder="Select crust"
                      :options="addOns.Crust"
                      :searchable="false"
                      :allow-empty="true"
                      @input="addExtra()"
                    >
                      <template
                        slot="singleLabel"
                        slot-scope="{ option }"
                      >{{ option.name }} (&#8377; {{ option.price }})</template>
                    </multiselect>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-divider class="mb-3" v-if="selected.description != null"></v-divider>
                {{ selected.description }}
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions v-show="!hidden">
            Total: ₹{{ selected.total }}
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <!-- <v-btn text>Order Now</v-btn> -->
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="saveToCart(selected)">Add To Cart</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-container>
  </template>
  <script>
  import Cart from "./Cart";
  import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
  export default {
    components: {
      Cart,
      Multiselect
    },
    data() {
      return {
        hidden: false,
        addDialog: false,
        items: [],
        loading: false,
        orders: [],
        cart: "0",
        selected: [],
        addOnExtra: [],
        addOnCrust: null,
        addOns: {
          Xtra: [],
          Crust: []
        }
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.initialize();
    },
    methods: {
      addTag(newTag) {
        const tag = {
          name: newTag,
          code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)
        };
        this.options.push(tag);
        this.value.push(tag);
      },
      nameWithPrice({ name, price }) {
        return `${name} (₹ ${price})`;
      },
      initialize() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.$axios
          .get("items")
          .then(res => {
            this.items = res.data;
            this.loading = false;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw err;
          });
        this.$axios
          .get("addOns")
          .then(res => {
            this.addOns.Xtra = res.data.xtra;
            this.addOns.Crust = res.data.crust;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw err;
          });
      },
      addToCart(item) {
        this.addDialog = true;
        this.selected = item;
        this.selected.quantity = 1;
        this.selected.Xtra = [];
        this.selected.Crust = null;
        this.selected.total = item.price;
        item.quantity = 1;
      },
      saveToCart(item) {
        item.Xtra = this.addOnExtra;
        item.Crust = this.addOnCrust != null ? this.addOnCrust : null;
        console.log(item);
        this.$store.commit("addedToCart", item);
        this.addDialog = false;
        this.addOnExtra = [];
        this.addOnCrust = null;
        this.$store.commit("setSnackbar", {
          text: "Item Added To Cart",
          color: "success"
        });
      },
      addExtra() {
        this.hidden = true;
        let total = parseInt(this.selected.price);
        if (this.addOnCrust != null) {
          total += this.addOnCrust.price;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.addOnExtra.length; i++) {
          total += parseInt(this.addOnExtra[i].price);
        }
        this.selected.total = total;
        this.hidden = false;
      }
    }
  };
  </script>

  <style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

store.js (vuex)

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    orders: [],
    cart: "0"
  },
  mutations: {
    addedToCart(state, data) {
      state.orders.push(data);
      state.cart = state.orders.length;
    }
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

Cart.vue

```
 <template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-label>My Cart</v-label>
        <v-row v-if="orders.length != 0">
          <v-col cols="12" v-for="(order, index) in orders" :key="index">
            <v-card @mouseenter="showHide(true, index)" @mouseleave="showHide(false, index)">
              <v-btn
                style="display: none"
                :id="'btn' + index"
                absolute
                top
                right
                icon
                color="red"
                @click="remove_from_cart(order)"
              >
                <v-icon>delete_forever</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <div class="d-flex flex-no-wrap justify-space-between">
                <v-col cols="12">
                  <v-avatar class="ma-1 float-right" size="70" tile>
                    <v-img :src="order.image"></v-img>
                  </v-avatar>
                  <v-card-title
                    v-show="!hidden"
                    class="pb-0"
                    style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 1rem;"
                  >{{ order.item_name.substring(0,40)+"..." }}</v-card-title>
                  <v-card-title>
                    Qnty. :
                    <v-btn class="mx-1" @click="decreaseQuantity(order)" outlined icon small>
                      <v-icon>mdi-minus</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    {{ order.quantity }}
                    <v-btn class="ml-1" @click="increaseQuantity(order)" outlined icon small>
                      <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-title class="pt-0">
                    <small>₹ {{ order.total }}</small>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn @click="dropAddOns(index)" text>
                      AddOns
                      <v-icon>{{ show ? "mdi-chevron-up" : "mdi-chevron-down" }}</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div :id="'addOn' + index" style="display: none;">
                      <v-divider></v-divider>
                      <v-row class="px-2">
                        <v-col cols="12">
                          <label class="typo__label">Xtra</label>
                          <multiselect
                            v-model="order.Xtra"
                            placeholder="Select extra"
                            :custom-label="nameWithPrice"
                            track-by="id"
                            :options="addOns.Xtra"
                            :multiple="true"
                            :taggable="true"
                            @tag="addTag"
                            @input="addExtra(order)"
                          ></multiselect>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col cols="12">
                          <label class="typo__label">Crust</label>
                          <multiselect
                            v-model="order.Crust"
                            track-by="id"
                            :custom-label="nameWithPrice"
                            placeholder="Select crust"
                            :options="addOns.Crust"
                            :searchable="false"
                            :allow-empty="true"
                            @input="addExtra(order)"
                          >
                            <template
                              slot="singleLabel"
                              slot-scope="{ option }"
                            >{{ option.name }} (&#8377; {{ option.price }})</template>
                          </multiselect>
                        </v-col>
                      </v-row>
                    </div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                </v-col>
              </div>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row v-else>
          <v-col>
            <v-label>
              <small>
                <i>Your card is empty! please add item first.</i>
              </small>
            </v-label>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" :lazy-validation="lazy">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-text-field v-model="form.name" :rules="nameRules" label="Name"></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.contact"
                :rules="contactRules"
                label="Contact"
                type="number"
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-textarea
                rows="1"
                :rules="address1Rules"
                v-model="form.address_line_1"
                label="Address"
                auto-grow
                clearable
                clear-icon="cancel"
              ></v-textarea>
              <v-label>TOTAL PRICE: {{ total }}</v-label>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn
                @click="orders.length != 0 ? placeOrder() : alertSnackBar()"
                width="100%"
                outlined
                color="indigo"
              >Place Order</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      valid: true,
      lazy: false,
      total: 0,
      hidden: false,
      show: false,
      addOns: {
        Xtra: [],
        Crust: []
      },
      loading: false,
      payment: null,
      rzpPayment: null,
      form: {},
      nameRules: [v => !!v || "Name is required"],
      contactRules: [v => !!v || "Contact is required"],
      address1Rules: [v => !!v || "Address is required"],
      // razorpay
      rzpOptions: {
        key: "env('rzpKey')",
        amount: 0,
        currency: "INR",
        name: "The Twisted Sisters Pizzeria",
        description: "",
        image: "/img/icons/apple-icon-precomposed.png",
        handler: this.submit,
        prefill: {
          name: "",
          email: "",
          contact: ""
        },
        notes: {
          user_id: null,
          order_id: null
        },
        theme: {
          color: "#ff7a7a"
        }
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["orders"])
  },
  watch: {
    orders() {
      this.updateTotal();
      this.initialize();
      this.getRzpKey();
      // console.log(o);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initialize();
    this.updateTotal();
    this.getRzpKey();
  },
  methods: {
    addTag(newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)
      };
      this.options.push(tag);
      this.value.push(tag);
    },
    nameWithPrice({ name, price }) {
      return `${name} (₹ ${price})`;
    },
    initialize() {
      this.$axios
        .get("addOns")
        .then(res => {
          this.addOns.Xtra = res.data.xtra;
          this.addOns.Crust = res.data.crust;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
    getRzpKey() {
      this.$axios
        .get("getKey")
        .then(res => {
          this.rzpOptions.key = res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
    remove_from_cart(order) {
      this.$store.commit("removedFromCart", order);
      this.updateTotal();
    },
    increaseQuantity(order) {
      this.hidden = true;
      let index = this.orders.indexOf(order);
      this.orders[index].total =
        this.orders[index].total / this.orders[index].quantity;

      this.$store.commit("increaseQuantity", index);

      this.orders[index].total =
        this.orders[index].total * this.orders[index].quantity;
      this.hidden = false;
      this.updateTotal();
    },
    decreaseQuantity(order) {
      this.hidden = true;
      let index = this.orders.indexOf(order);
      if (this.orders[index].quantity >= 2) {
        let singlePrice =
          this.orders[index].total / this.orders[index].quantity;
        this.orders[index].quantity -= 1;
        this.orders[index].total -= singlePrice;
      }
      this.hidden = false;
      this.updateTotal();
    },
    addExtra(order) {
      this.hidden = true;
      let index = this.orders.indexOf(order);
      let total = 0;
      if (this.orders[index].Crust != null) {
        total += this.orders[index].Crust.price * this.orders[index].quantity;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < order.Xtra.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt(order.Xtra[i].price) * this.orders[index].quantity;
      }
      this.orders[index].total =
        total +
        parseInt(this.orders[index].price) * this.orders[index].quantity;
      this.hidden = false;
      this.updateTotal();
    },
    showHide(data, index) {
      if (data == true) {
        document.getElementById("btn" + index).style =
          "background-color: #fff; border: 1px dashed #000; display: block; z-index: 5;";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("btn" + index).style = "display: none";
      }
    },
    dropAddOns(index) {
      if (document.getElementById("addOn" + index).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById("addOn" + index).style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("addOn" + index).style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    updateTotal() {
      this.total = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
        this.total += parseFloat(this.orders[i].total);
      }
    },
    placeOrder() {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        this.form.items = this.orders;
        this.rzpOptions.amount = this.total * 100;
        this.rzpOptions.prefill.name = this.form.name;
        this.rzpOptions.prefill.contact = this.form.contact;
        this.$axios
          .post("customer/order", this.form)
          .then(res => {
            this.initRazorpay();
            this.rzpOptions.notes.order_id = res.data.order_id;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            throw err;
          });
      }
    },
    findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i][attr] === value) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    },
    alertSnackBar() {
      this.$store.commit("setSnackbar", {
        text: "Empty Cart",
        color: "red"
      });
    },
    initRazorpay() {
      /* eslint-disable */
      let rzp = new Razorpay(this.rzpOptions);
      rzp.open();
    },
    submit(response) {
      this.$axios
        .post("save-payment", {
          payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id,
          order_id: this.rzpOptions.notes.order_id,
          amount: this.total
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.notifyUser(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    },
    notifyUser(res) {
      this.$store.commit("setSnackbar", {
        text: res.data.success,
        color: "success"
      });
      this.$refs.form.reset();
      this.$store.commit("addOrder", "order");
      this.$eventBus.$emit("socket", {
        event: "order-submitted"
      });
      this.form = {};
    }
  },
  created() {
    var imported = document.createElement("script");
    imported.src = "https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js";
    document.head.appendChild(imported);
  }
};
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem could be here:

```
    <v-col cols="12" md="4" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
```

you are using the item ID as key, but if there are two elements with same id, the key won't be unique anymore.
You should use another strategy for the key, ad example by adding the index to the key to make it unique.

```
<v-col cols="12" md="4" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index+'-'+item.id">
```

Be advised that using the index is not considered good practice, because when your array changes, indexes will change too forcing the elements to re-render.

Comment: the problem is inside `cart.vue` only